# изображение по размеру Button

Tags: android

Есть tableLayout 3 на 3. Каждая ячейка это button или imageButton, без разницы. При нажатии нужно установить им картинку. Попробовал эти два метода:
**setBackgroundResourse** и **setImageResource**, в результате ячейка растягивается по размеру картинки. Как сделать так, чтобы размер ячейки остался тот же?

Comment: растягивается скорее всего потому, что у кнопки свойства задающие высоту ширину определяются как wrap_content (т.е. соответствуют внутреннему содержимому). Если тебе нужен статический размер, то задавай явно с указанием dp

Comment: @Sviat Volkov tableLayout стоит в match_parent, и каждая строка в match_parent, и каждая ячейка.И затем с помощью веса weight=1 я сделал все ячейки одинакового размера.

Comment: При использовании веса выставляют 0dp на width если ориентация горизонтальная или на height если вертикальная.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить такие свойства в xml `ImageButton`:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```